# Capacitors, Formula for Energy

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I had a quick question; As you know there are three formulas for calculating the Potential Energy of a Capacitor
U=Potential Energy

$Q$=Charge

$C$=Capacitance

$V$=Voltage/Potential Difference

1) $U=\frac{1}{2}Q\,V$

2) $U=\frac{1}{2} Q^2/C$

3) $U=\frac{1}{2}C V^2$

How should one decide when to use which formula?

I think that in a given scenario, if a particular variable is constant for instance the charge, then one should use the second Equation (Assuming that Capacitance is constant and the Voltage is varying).

Comment: Your question lacks research. You could have googled for it and got an answer.

Comment: You should focus on how to solve problems in general.  With this system, you could have two equations and two unknowns, using Q=CV.  You're too focused on "which formula to use."

Answer (score 2):

These are all the same equation, because $C = \frac{Q}{V}$. You can convert. As long as you know any two of $Q$, $C$, and $V$, you can use the equation that references those two, or use the formula above to convert to another one.